# Kafka Connect. How to handle List of custom object, when specifying schema and building SourceRecord value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have dto CryptoNews. Which contains

```
List<Currencies> currencies
```

I would like to save **"currencies"** field to **SourceRecord** when constructing it.
Can't figure out how to:

1. Declare it in schema.
2. Pass it to Struct object when building value.

My attempts end in this exception:
**Invalid Java object for schema type STRUCT: class com.dto.Currencies**

Kafka Connect doesn't provide explicit example how to do handle case, when object in List requires it's own Schema.
I also tried to apply similar approach as in Kafka test cases, but it doesn't work. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/StructTest.java#L95-L98

### How to do this?

```
kafka-connect-api version: 0.10.2.0-cp1
value and key converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
no avro used


CryptoNews implements Serializable {

   // omitted fields

    private List<Currencies> currencies;

}

class Currencies {

    private String code;
    private String title;
    private String slug;
    private String url;

}
```

**SchemaConfiguration**

```
public static final Integer FIRST_VERSION = 1;
public static final String CURRENCIES_SCHEMA_NAME = "currencies";
 
 
 
public static final Schema NEWS_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct().name("News")
            .version(FIRST_VERSION)
            .field(CURRENCIES_SCHEMA_NAME, CURRENCIES_SCHEMA)
            // simple fields ommited for brevity.
            .build();
 
    
 
public static final Schema CURRENCIES_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.array(
            SchemaBuilder.struct()
            .field(CODE_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(TITLE_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(SLUG_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(URL_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .optional()
            .build()
    )
            .optional()
            .name(CURRENCIES_SCHEMA_NAME)
            .version(FIRST_VERSION)
            .build();
```

**SourceTask**

```
return new SourceRecord(
                sourcePartition(),
                sourceOffset(cryptoNews),
                config.getString(TOPIC_CONFIG),
                null,
                CryptoNewsSchema.NEWS_KEY_SCHEMA,
                buildRecordKey(cryptoNews),
                CryptoNewsSchema.NEWS_SCHEMA,
                buildRecordValue(cryptoNews),
                Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
        );

 
 
public Struct buildRecordValue(CryptoNews cryptoNews){
        Struct valueStruct = new Struct(CryptoNewsSchema.NEWS_SCHEMA);
 
        // Produces Invalid Java object for schema type STRUCT: class com.dto.Currencies
        List<Currencies> currencies = cryptoNews.getCurrencies();
        if (currencies != null) {
            valueStruct.put(CurrenciesSchema.CURRENCIES_SCHEMA_NAME, currencies);
        }
 
        return valueStruct;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

worker.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:29092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=true

rest.port=8086
rest.host.name=127.0.0.1
offset.storage.file.filename=offsets/standalone.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
```

Comment: Don't implement Java Serializable. Can you not use Avro or Protobuf, or simply JSON?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I deleted implementation of Serializable, exception is still the same. I don't use Avro and Protobuf

Comment: Removing the interface wasn't to fix the problem, it was to point out that you should ideally not use Java serialization for Kafka events. What does your producer code look like? If you use `JSONConverter` with default `schemas.enable=true` and properly write the `"schema"` and `"payload"` fields in the Producer code for the JSON data, then the Converter will automatically know what to do with SourceRecord schemas... Or are you trying to actually write a SourceConnector from some "crytpo news" API?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, I'm trying to write a SourceConnector for crypto-news API. Previously I used Serializable, because I sent is as json through Kafka in another application. Now I copied the same DTO's to construct source connector for API. I agree that there is no need to use Serializable here. Also added my properties to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a `List<Struct>`

Here's a full unit test example

First, an interface that will help

```
public interface ConnectPOJOConverter<T> {
  Schema getSchema();
  T fromConnectData(Struct s);
  Struct toConnectData(T t);
}
```

```
class ArrayStructTest {

  public static final Schema CURRENCY_ITEM_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct()
      .version(1)
      .name(Currency.class.getName())
      .doc("A currency item")
      .field("code", Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
      .field("title", Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
      .field("slug", Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
      .field("url", Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
      .build();

  static final ConnectPOJOConverter<Currency> CONVERTER = new CurrencyConverter();

  @Test
  void myTest() {
    // Given
    List<Currency> currencies = new ArrayList<>();
    // TODO: Get from external source
    currencies.add(new Currency("200", "Hello", "/slug", "http://localhost"));
    currencies.add(new Currency("200", "World", "/slug", "http://localhost"));

    // When: build Connect Struct data
    Schema valueSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct()
        .name("CryptoNews")
        .doc("A record holding a list of currency items")
        .version(1)
        .field("currencies", SchemaBuilder.array(CURRENCY_ITEM_SCHEMA).required().build())
        .build();
    final List<Struct> items = currencies.stream()
        .map(CONVERTER::toConnectData)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // In the SourceTask, this is what goes into the SourceRecord along with the valueSchema
    Struct value = new Struct(valueSchema);
    value.put("currencies", items);

    // Then
    assertDoesNotThrow(value::validate);
    Object itemsFromStruct = value.get("currencies");
    assertInstanceOf(List.class, itemsFromStruct);
    //noinspection unchecked
    List<Object> data = (List<Object>) itemsFromStruct; // could also use List<Struct>
    assertEquals(2, data.size(), "same size");
    assertInstanceOf(Struct.class, data.get(0), "Object list still has type information");
    Struct firstStruct = (Struct) data.get(0);
    assertEquals("Hello", firstStruct.get("title"));
    currencies = data.stream()
        .map(o -> (Struct) o)
        .map(CONVERTER::fromConnectData)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)  // in case converter has errors, could return null
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertTrue(currencies.size() <= data.size());
    assertEquals("World", currencies.get(1).getTitle(), "struct parsing data worked");
  }

  static class CurrencyConverter implements ConnectPOJOConverter<Currency> {

    @Override
    public Schema getSchema() {
      return CURRENCY_ITEM_SCHEMA;
    }

    @Override
    public Currency fromConnectData(Struct s) {
      // simple conversion, but more complex types could throw errors
      return new Currency(
          s.getString("code"),
          s.getString("title"),
          s.getString("url"),
          s.getString("slug")
      );
    }

    @Override
    public Struct toConnectData(Currency c) {
      Struct s = new Struct(getSchema());
      s.put("code", c.getCode());
      s.put("title", c.getTitle());
      s.put("url", c.getUrl());
      s.put("slug", c.getSlug());
      return s;
    }
  }

}
```

The alternative approach is to just use a String schema, and use Jackson `ObjectMapper` to get a JSON string, then let `JSONConverter` handle the rest.

```
final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
final Schema valueSchema = Schema.STRING_SCHEMA;
output.put("schema", new TextNode("TODO")); // replace with JSONConverter schema

// for-each currency
Map<String, JsonNode> output = new HashMap<>();
try {
  output.put("payload", om.readTree(om.writeValueAsBytes(currency))); // write and parse to not double-encode
  
  String value = om.writeValueAsString(output);
  SourceRecord r = new SourceRecord(...., valueSchema, value);
  records.add(r); // poll return result
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO: handle
}
// end for-each

return records;
```